# Null pointer exception in lambda expression

Tags: lambda, nullpointerexception, javafx

I have JavaFx application in which there is a ListView named roomList. I use following line of code to check if something from ListView is selected :

```
    roomList.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue)   -> showRoomElements(newValue));
```

and if some item is selected then according to which is selected I change some text on some labels. That works fine.
Problem comes when, using some other menu, I change items in **roomList**.It still works on changing labels but i have Null pointer exception.

```
    Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException
at homeautomation.view.HomePageController.showRoomElements(HomePageController.java:207)
at homeautomation.view.HomePageController.lambda$setHomeAutomation$1(HomePageController.java:59)
at homeautomation.view.HomePageController$$Lambda$276/1011775954.changed(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper$SingleChange.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:182)
at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:81)
at javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyObjectWrapper$ReadOnlyPropertyImpl.fireValueChangedEvent(ReadOnlyObjectWrapper.java:176)
at javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyObjectWrapper.fireValueChangedEvent(ReadOnlyObjectWrapper.java:142)
at javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.markInvalid(ObjectPropertyBase.java:112)
at javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.set(ObjectPropertyBase.java:145)
at javafx.scene.control.SelectionModel.setSelectedItem(SelectionModel.java:102)
at javafx.scene.control.MultipleSelectionModelBase.lambda$new$34(MultipleSelectionModelBase.java:67)
at javafx.scene.control.MultipleSelectionModelBase$$Lambda$192/1369453379.invalidated(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper$SingleInvalidation.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:137)
at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:81)
at javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyIntegerWrapper$ReadOnlyPropertyImpl.fireValueChangedEvent(ReadOnlyIntegerWrapper.java:176)
at javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyIntegerWrapper.fireValueChangedEvent(ReadOnlyIntegerWrapper.java:142)
at javafx.beans.property.IntegerPropertyBase.markInvalid(IntegerPropertyBase.java:113)
at javafx.beans.property.IntegerPropertyBase.set(IntegerPropertyBase.java:146)
at javafx.scene.control.SelectionModel.setSelectedIndex(SelectionModel.java:68)
at javafx.scene.control.ListView$ListViewBitSetSelectionModel.updateItemsObserver(ListView.java:1287)
at javafx.scene.control.ListView$ListViewBitSetSelectionModel.access$000(ListView.java:1186)
at javafx.scene.control.ListView$1.invalidated(ListView.java:426)
at javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.markInvalid(ObjectPropertyBase.java:111)
at javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.set(ObjectPropertyBase.java:145)
at javafx.scene.control.ListView.setItems(ListView.java:394)
at homeautomation.view.HomePageController.handleSelectFirstFloor(HomePageController.java:141)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1759)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1645)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
at javafx.scene.control.MenuItem.fire(MenuItem.java:462)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.ContextMenuContent$MenuItemContainer.doSelect(ContextMenuContent.java:1364)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.ContextMenuContent$MenuItemContainer.lambda$createChildren$324(ContextMenuContent.java:1317)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.ContextMenuContent$MenuItemContainer$$Lambda$295/2103054710.handle(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3724)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3452)
at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1728)
at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2461)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:348)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:273)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:382)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:553)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:925)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$141(WinApplication.java:102)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$$Lambda$37/728890494.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: When you deselect all items in the ListView (e.g. by changing the items altogether), then `newValue` in your listener is `null`, causing your NullPointerException.

Comment: Is there a way to fix it ?

Comment: Just check for null in your `showRoomElements` method.

Comment: I also suggest using bindings instead of listeners if possible. For that I would have to know what `showRoomElements` is doing.

Comment: showRoomElements is just changing text on labels

Comment: Is it changing text of a _fixed_ number of Labels (e.g. 5), or does it remove and create Labels as necessary?

Comment: Its fixed number. `roomList.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue)
                -> {
            if (newValue!=null) {
                showRoomElements(newValue);              
            }
        });` This worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I suggested in the comments, I recommend refactoring your code so that it uses bindings instead of listeners where possible.

Say that you have a class `Room` like this:

```
class Room {
    String getFoo();
    StringProperty barProperty();
}
```

and you want to display "foo" and "bar" attributes of the selected room in `fooLabel` and `barLabel`, respectively. I will use [EasyBind](https://github.com/TomasMikula/EasyBind) to create bindings derived from the "selected room" property.

```
// wrap the selectedItemProperty to get the map and flatMap methods used below
MonadicObservableValue<Room> selectedRoom = EasyBind.monadic(
        roomList.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty());

fooLabel.textProperty().bind(selectedRoom.map(Room::getFoo));
barLabel.textProperty().bind(selectedRoom.flatMap(Room::barProperty));
```

Note that when `selectedRoom` holds `null` (i.e. no room selected), the labels' text will be set to null, displaying no text. If instead you wanted to display some default text, do this:

```
fooLabel.textProperty().bind(
        selectedRoom.map(Room::getFoo).orElse("No room selected"));
```

#### Bindings are better style

Preferring bindings over listeners is better style because a binding states more declaratively what the text of `fooLabel` is. Here it says

> `fooLabel` shows the *'foo'* attribute of the selected room, or the text "No room selected".

Compare this to the listener approach, where

> `fooLabel` shows whatever it is told to show from whatever part of the code.

In other words, every listener is a *side effect* and side effects result in unreadable spaghetti code.

Comment: Thanks, I'll use this.